# What is the exactly the term "10" in Coq?

Tags: coq

A very basic question about Coq (with Init libraries): the term `10` is of type `nat`,
and the type `nat` is defined inductively:

```
Inductive nat : Set :=
  | O : nat
  | S : nat -> nat.
```

**Q1.** But is "10" a "shortcut" of `S(S(...S(0)...))`?

**Q2.** Is there a shortest (formal) proof of the following lemma? (without using omega)

```
Lemma gg : 3 <= 10.
apply le_S.
apply le_S.
apply le_S.
apply le_S.
apply le_S.
apply le_S.
apply le_S.
apply le_n.
Qed.
```

In other words does a proof of `n <= m` (with only Peano axioms), require exponential length?

Comment: For constants the proof can be long, but usually proofs are about variables, so they are shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A1. Right.

A2. As far as I can tell from definition of `le`(`<=`), you have to use `le_S` and `le_n` to construct a proof of it.

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
    le_n : n <= n | le_S : forall m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m
```

... unless you define a lemma to make your work easier.

You can do something like this:

```
Lemma gg : 3 <= 10.
Proof.
  do 7 (apply le_S).
  apply le_n.
Qed.
```

... or

```
Lemma gg' : 3 <= 10.
Proof. repeat constructor. Qed.
```

... or go the other way around:

```
Lemma le_s : forall n m, n <= m -> S n <= S m.
Proof.
  intros. induction H. constructor.
  constructor. apply IHle.
Qed.

Lemma gg'' : 3 <= 10.
Proof.
  pose proof (le_n 0).
  do 3 (apply le_s in H).
  do 7 (apply le_S in H).
  apply H.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 6):

Q1: Yes.

Q2: You can probably use the technique of proof by reflection to eliminate such trivial large proofs. This chapter explains how and why you would want to do that:

http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Reflection.html

Answer (score 5):

Below is an example for Ptival's answer.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Check @eq_refl.
Check leb_complete.

Goal 3 <= 10. Proof. apply leb_complete. apply eq_refl. Qed.

Goal 30 <= 100. Proof. apply leb_complete. apply eq_refl. Qed.

Goal 300 <= 1000. Proof. apply leb_complete. apply eq_refl. Qed.
```

Come to think of it, isn't `omega` also a form of proof by reflection? Or is it programmed in OCaml?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I don't know why the suggested edit on my answer did not go through, this is very helpful.